# Grails POST Request Charset Encoding

Tags: rest, grails, character-encoding, grails-controller

Grails 2.3.2:

This new version of grails (2.3) gives me the possibility to create a REST endpoint by extending the RestfulController class. I extend that class but when I POST to that endpoint with special characters these characters change.

I have these lines in my config file:

```
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

And all my pages and requests use the UTF-8 charset.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if your controller file is in UTF-8. If the data comes from the database, check if you're using the correct jdbc url.

Comment: Yes, my controller file is in UTF-8, my data is coming from the database and the jdbc url is correct. And when I do a GET request to my endpoint the special chars appear correctly. It's only when I do a POST or a PUT request. I tried to do the POST manually but I've got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

A REST endpoint use HTTP connections, the gsp encoding is applied only for GSP views and though the converters apply the encoding as JSON formaters configuration the problem is in the HTTP connection.

The web container layer is the first filter and it affects the URI requested. Then you can apply a few container parameters as a JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=UTF-8
-DjavaEncoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.io.encoding=UTF-8
```

Posibly you already resolved, but I hope that this response will be util for another cases.